# UICollectionView : how to animate the change of a cell?

Tags: animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

- In a initial state, my collection view has three cells, in one section : `cell1`, `cell2` and `cell3`.
- In the next state, the first cell change and becomes `cell1_bis`. It has the same size.

> Is it possible to animate this change `cell1 -> cell1_bis`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

Proceed this way:

```
 [self.collectionView

 performBatchUpdates:^
 {
     NSIndexPath * whereTheChangeIs = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:row
                                                          inSection:section] ;

     [self.collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:@[whereTheChangeIs]] ;
     [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[whereTheChangeIs]] ;
 }

 completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
     // nothing
 }] ;
```

### Question

Unfortunately, the following does not work. Bug?

```
 [self.collectionView

 performBatchUpdates:^
 {
     NSIndexPath * whereTheChangeIs = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:row
                                                          inSection:section] ;

     [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[whereTheChangeIs]] ;
 }

 completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {
     // nothing
 }] ;
```